# CiviEvent URLs - differ between Dashboard & Manage Events

Tags: civievent, civimail, tracked-links

I'm not sure when this broke, as I was just alerted to it.  Running Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.7.6.

Events receive differently structured URLs in Manage Events and Events Dashboard.

Manage Events shows a URL like http://www.mydomain.com/civicrm/event/info?id=66&reset=1

Event Dashboard shows a URL like http://www.mydomain.com/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=66

Both URLs work and take you to the event page.  However, if you embed the Dashboard URL into a mailing with link tracking enabled, the link will not redirect properly.  You receive the error below:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Could not find valid value for id

Return to home page.

So, depending on how you navigated to the event page to obtain the URL, the link may or may not work when embedded into the mailings.

I'm not sure if there is a reason behind the differing formats for the two pages and it needs to be that way or if the resolution is in the redirection.

Comment: Ah, I found how to fix, but still not sure if there is a reason why.
Change line 60 in templates/CRM/Event?page?Dashboard.tpl to
        <td class="crm-event-eventTitle"><a href="{crmURL p="civicrm/event/info" q="id=`$id`&reset=1"}" title="{ts}View event info page{/ts}">{$values.eventTitle}</a>

Comment: Issue CRM-18384 created to document bug as I was able to reproduce on the demo site.

Comment: The CiviCRM Upcoming Events block for Drupal also has the swapped URL, like the Dashboard, and it's using {$ev.url} to input the URL.  I'm not sure where that is defined to correct.